# jQuery - Dynamically Load Form and Submit with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load a form into a dialog using `.load(url)` and then enabling AJAX submit on it. It does load the form into the dialog, but it seems it completely ignoring my jQuery code and just submits it normally with page refresh.

I use the AJAX code on multiple sites (not dynamic) and that works just as intended.

Here I will show you the code:

javascript.js; wrapped into a ready() to submit the dynamic form

```
$("#dbsearch").submit(function(event) {
    alert('click!');
    var data = $("#dbsearch").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            }
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

form.php; loaded into a modal

```
<form method="post" id="dbsearch">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <label for="method" class="control-label">Search By</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="method" name="method">
            <option>Choose...</option>
            <option value="content-type">Search By Name</option>
            <option value="release-date">Search By Release Date</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <label for="value" class="control-label">Value</label>
        <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="value" placeholder="Enter a term...">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
    </div>
</form>
```

What can be causing this? Is it because it's dynamically loaded into a dialog? If so, what would be the best way to resolve such issue?

---

Updated JS Code

```
$("#dbsearch").delegate("#dbsearch input[type=submit]", "click", function(event) {
    alert('click!');
    var data = $("#dbsearch").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            }
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are using a direct event handler instead of a delegated event handler. Event delegation allows us to attach an event listener to elements that exist now or in the future.

https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Example (not tested):

```
$("#dbsearch").delegate("#dbsearch input[type=submit]", "click", function(event) {
  // Your code here
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you for your input on my question. Sadly this does not seem to work. I've had a look in the docs but after trying out some examples it still seems to submit like a normal form.

Comment: In your example code, did the alert in your JS trigger?

Comment: It unfortunately did not trigger the alert

Comment: Are you able to use delegation to get the alert to trigger? This is the first issue to resolve, then need to prevent default submit of form.

Comment: I've tried multiple things from changing "click" to "submit", and also removing `[type=submit]` to see if it triggers on any input but unfortunately I get zero response from the jquery. To make sure the cache isn't the issue I reload the page using CTRL+F5 every time I test things.

Answer (score 0):

You can load your code in your dialog container element by using "html" method, it will load your js functions on the browser.

```
$.get(url, function(result){
   $('mydialogdiv').html(result);
});
```